# Koltin Multiplatform Multi Module JVM/JS Project Setup

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I need to convert existing multi-module jvm project into a multiplatform project.

```
//Exisiting Modules: (JVM Project)
core
data
app
app_server
utils
db
//Need to add:
app_frontend (Kotlin/JS)
```

Need to share data module between JVM and JS
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to share your data module between JVM and JS. For this, your data module has to be a multiplatform project targeting JVM and JS. The most basic setup would be:

```
// build.gradle.kts

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
}

group = "data"

kotlin {
    jvm()
    js { browser { binaries.executable() } }

    sourceSets["commonMain"].dependencies {
        // Your dependencies...
    }
}
```

Other modules can be built with "regular" plugins targeting a specific platform, so your JVM modules won't need any adjustments. The basic setup for JS would be:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.js")
}

group = "app_frontend"

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":data"))
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-js"))
}
kotlin {
    js {
        browser { binaries.executable() }
    }
}
```

Also checkout the official documentation about multiplatform programming:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-intro.html
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-library.html#creating-a-project